# QImage ошибка создания картинки из буфера

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

я создаю изображение из буфера и вывожу его, но у меня получается картинка со сдвигом в кадре. картинка в буфере в формате ВМР. как можно это поправить?

```
QImage st_image((uchar*)image,hor_size,ver_size,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
ch_pic->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(st_image.mirrored(false,true)));
ch_pic->show();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для отображения изображения ВМР из буфера, при сдвиге кадра, лучше использовать создание изображения из массива байтов.

```
QPixmap mpixmap;
mpixmap.loadFromData((const uchar*)mask_image, mask_image_size);
lbl->setPixmap(mpixmap2);
```